# Deploy dash application on a local server for multiple users

Tags: mod-wsgi, plotly-dash

Based on the discussion [Deploying Dash app on a 'local' server (with external access) securely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64790502/deploying-dash-app-on-a-local-server-with-external-access-securely), what would be a way to deploy a dash application on a local server using mod_wsgi, but whenever a user (or a different browser tab) access the mod_wsgi server address, a new dash application object is created?

Comment: Why do you need a new object?

Comment: so that when another person goes to the wsgi address, a new dash app instance is created. Otherwise, two persons would use the same app and changes made by one would be seen by the other.

Comment: What do you mean by "changes"? A key design principle of Dash is top keep the server stateless.

Comment: @emher, I refer to the interactivity of the Dash app. Specifically, I have an app that lets the user define some values via sliders. Currently, if i fire up the wsgi on one server and interact with the app, then when I go to the wsgi server on a different tab (or laptop) the slider values set by one are visible to the other. My question is how to have the same dash app accessible from different users, but each one to work independent of the other.

Comment: That doesn't sound like default Dash behavior. Can you post code demonstrating this behavior?